# Is there a genealogy program on Ubuntu that will **synchronize** with Ancestry.com?

Tags: sync

I know there are a number of genealogy programs / options, I am looking to see if anyone has had any success / pointers into something that can synchronize with Ancestry... either FTM2017 or RootsMagic 7.5 with Wine or a synchronization plug-in for Gramps? Any directions/help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Synchronise isn't an option that I know is available. Import/export of GEDCOM files is the common procedure to exchange data.

Follow the instructions at gramps site, https://gramps-project.org/wiki/index.php/Import_from_another_genealogy_program

Please note that ancestry.com GEDCOM format isn't consistent.

Quote from the URL:

*The GEDCOM layout used by Ancestry for each item seems to not be consistent, and might change depending on the time at which the initial entry was made into the Ancestry.com tree.*

Comment: Unfortunately you can't just re-upload the GEDCOM from GRAMPS to Ancestry.COM, so this doesn't work. I was hoping maybe someone developed a plugin that worked with their APIs. https://www.programmableweb.com/api/family-tree-maker